# SQL Server select all max and min data in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
+----+------+
| id | data |
+-----------+
| 1  |  a   |
| 2  |  b   |
| 3  |  a   |
| 3  |  c   |
+----+------+
```

I need to select data `[a,b,c]`.

Comment: in which DB can you get the same ID for different data points?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want the distinct values in the second column?

```
select distinct data
from t;
```